# Is there a cooling off period before a further UK Standard Visitor visa can be requested?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

My sister is from India and is currently in the UK on a visitor visa expiring in February. We will be moving homes next year and so far have not found any good childcare at our new location. We need a family member to support us.

Is it possible to re-apply for a UK visitor visa soon after reaching India or is there a cooling period before a visitor visa can be re-applied for?

Comment: There is no cooling off period for UK Visitor Visas, you can apply back-to-back if you want.  But remember the rule "...will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home..." is grounds for refusal.

Comment: If your sister is specifically coming to the UK because you can't find good childcare then you may be in a grey area with regard to her working in the UK. If she comes in order to do work that would be otherwise done by a British national, that may be grounds for refusal.

Comment: It is about having a smooth transition and settling in at the new place, we need a family member to come-over and help us. Does it still look a grey area?

Comment: Well, yes, obviously if you are using the visitor programme to import child care, it's abuse.  If they spot it, you can kiss your sponsorship capacity goodbye.

Comment: The UK considers child care, even for relatives, as "unpaid work" not allowed on a standard visitor visa. People have been refused entry, removed and deported for exactly this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnMZHU1kopo#t=33m54s